# Product Version property for msi file

Tags: properties, wix, windows-installer, version, windows-explorer

I have a msi that is developed using wix.

When I build this wix project, the msi files comes into the Output Directory of the project and with that the DateModified, Type and Size properties are reflected in the windows explorer.

But the ProductVersion property is coming blank, though in my wix project, I have specified the ProductVersion in the product tag.

So, I want to know how can I display that ProductVersion with the msi file entry in Windows Explorer.

Thanks in advance